# Не переключается страница WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

При старте программы, окно должно переключаться на страницу 1, но висит белый экран и ничего не происходит.  XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DL2new.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DL2new"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Установка" Height="450" Width="800" Icon="123451.ico"
        Topmost="True">
    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="MainFrame" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="442" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="792" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Navigated="MainFrame_Navigated"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CS:

```
using System.Windows;
 
namespace DL2new
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
          public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainFrame.Content = new Page1();
        }
 
        private void MainFrame_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
 
        }
    }
}
```

Думаю уже часа 2.

Comment: Перенесите код с пастбина в ваш вопрос. Старайтесь не прикреплять код скринами или сторонними ссылками

Comment: @Aarnihauta сделал

Comment: А у вас в `Page1` какой-нибудь контент есть? Какие-нибудь там элементы или текст.. может у Вас просто сама страница пустая и Вам кажется, что не переключается, хотя всё переключилось, но это визуально неотличимо ибо основное окно идентично внешне `Page1`

Comment: @Aarnihauta Да, есть. И кнопки, и картинки, и текстбоксы.

Comment: В главном окне укажите следующий код: `<Frame Source="Page1.xaml">`. Если нужна навигация, то обращайтесь к вашему фрейму и используйте `MainFrame.Navigate(new ConcretePage())`

Comment: @Aarnihauta Только что проверил и узнал, что не переключается только на Page1, на Page2 переключается спокойно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде `MainWindow.xaml` измените `Source` у `<Frame>`: `<Frame Source="Page1.xaml">`

Так же, можно внутри конструктра `MainWindow.cs` вызвать метод `MainFrame.Navigate`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.MainFrame.Navigate(new Page1());
}
```

Чтобы переключаться между страницами:
`MainFrame.Navigate(new ConcretePage());`